# Sort object pairs into separate bins

Tags: algorithm

I have N object pairs (master copy/slave copy) all with the same size. I wish to distribute the copies among M bins each with a **different** capacity so that no bin will include both the master and slave copy.

What's the most efficient algorithm? And **more importantly** what's the most efficient algorithm to find out if there is a possible solution for a given input (without actually generating the solution)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to imagine anything better thn brute force: track the M bins in a prioirty queue by descending remaining capacity, and add each object pair to the first two bins in the queue; rebalance queue and repeat. Solution exists if total capacity of the M bins >= 2*N.

That would seem to be complexity O(N * log M)

Note: For exactly three bins, no solution exists for N > M1 + M2 where Mn is the capacity of bin n sorted by descending capacity for n in range 0..M, regardless of the capacity of M0.

Likewise for exactly 2 bins, solutions exist only for N <= M1.

Comment: Algorithm sounds correct but if there's a single bin with 2*N capacity there's no solution.

Comment: @user1532059: Answer updated to also note the two and three bin excxeptions.

Comment: There can be many more exceptions, question is how to figure out for a given input if there's a solution?

Comment: @hyrax: I am not sure there are more exceptions. Can you think of a specific exception for M > 3? The problem reminds me of the game Nim, where the special cases all arose at the bottom end.

Comment: N=5, M=4, Capacity(M0)=100, Capacity(M1-3)=1

Comment: I think the solution is:  
`for each M: sum += min(N,capcity(M)); return sum >= N*2;`

Answer (score 0):

A simple solutions is:

Sort the M buckets in descending order according to their capacity: x1, x2,..,xm

Pick the topmost two buckets, assign an object to that pair, decrement the available capacities of the two buckets and rearrange the buckets. You can use a heap to keep track of buckets and the complexity is close to O(n)

Keep repeating until all the objects are allocated.